# What are the envelopes used for giving money on special occasions called?

Tags: word-requests

On special occasions such as weddings and on New Year's Day, envelopes that have prewritten Kanji on them and other decorative items are used for giving money.

Is there a generic term for these envelopes, or do they have specific names for specific events?

Comment: Have you tried google? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%ABgi-bukuro

Comment: I was searching for a generic term, not just involving weddings.

Comment: Then how about this: https://alicegordenker.wordpress.com/tag/noshibukuro/

Comment: Could you reconsider using the tag `word-choice`, which is defined as "The differences between two or more words or phrases and how to select the best one for a given situation"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic term is [金封【きんぷう】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E5%B0%81), but Japanese people do not use this word commonly. Common words are:

香典【こうでん】袋【ぶくろ】 for black and white ones used on funerals:

[image: ＜香典袋＞]

(ご)祝儀【しゅうぎ】袋【ぶくろ】 or のし袋【ぶくろ】 for colorful ones used for weddings or other happy occassions:

[image: ＜のし袋＞]

ポチ袋【ふくろ】 or お年玉袋 used specifically for [お年玉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_New_Year#Otoshidama):

[image: ＜ポチ袋＞]

<sub>(Images from photoAC)</sub>